# Error al Compilar App Xamarin I-OS en Jenkins Target _CompileITunesMetadata

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, macos, jenkins, mono

tengo una app de IOS que quiero compilar en Jenkis y me sale el error:

> Target _CompileITunesMetadata:
>       /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets:
>   error : Error executing task CompileITunesMetadata: Path is empty
>             Build FAILED.

estoy buscando por todos lados y no encuentro que es lo que me falta. A alguien le paso algo similar?

Adjunto link con 
[Log y config](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19EPRWwoNesIeEcspji9z2GzhGgP3q-tN?usp=sharing)
Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hay código, Jenkis es un software de integración continua, se debe configurar para que compile.

Comment: Lo adjunte en un link porque era mucho para ponerlo en la descripción

Comment: @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo es posible ver tu csproj ?, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys lo agregue al directorio junto con los logs

Comment: ¿Que guía seguiste para hacer la configuración de Jenkins?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/

Comment: @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo segun lo que investigue intenta primero borrar los directorios bin y debug y genera de nuevo con un build las dlls. (por si acaso copia dichos archivos en otra ruta para después poder revertir la acción ). Me dices como te va.

Comment: Hola @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo, ¿puedes probar a añadir `/p:CodesignEntitlements="Entitlements.plist"` a los parámetros  de la llamada a `xbuild`? Según he leído [aquí](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93361/how-to-build-for-appstore-with-xbuild) podría ser el problema, también añadiendo `/p:BuildIpa=true` 
Yo intenté configurar la build con el agente de TFS2015 y no lo conseguí, aunque mis problemas tenían que ver con los certificados y perfiles de aprovisionamiento, mi próximo intento será con VSTS :-)

Comment: esta asi, edito la pregunta y agrego un print